# ion-navbar background image not appearing - showing only white - Ionic 3

Tags: html, css, image, ionic-framework, background

I have an `ion-header` section like this:

```
<ion-header (swipeRight)="toProfile()">
  <ion-navbar #clickme class="itemadspace" [@slideDown]="downState" no-lines no-padding>
    <h3 class="feedtitle">Stylist Feed</h3>
    <div (tap)="loadPost()" class='pluscontainer'>
      <ion-icon class='plussy' name="add"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </ion-navbar>

  ...

</ion-header>
```

The CSS for `ion-navbar` is the `itemadspace` class is:

```
    .itemadspace {
        z-index: 1;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-image: url('../../assets/tresemme.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

No image shows, the background for the `ion-navbar` component is white. Any idea how to get the background image to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INstead of adding a s class. you can overwrite the theme.
You can add this code in variable.scss at bottom.

```
ion-header{
    ion-navbar{
        div.toolbar-background{
             background-image: url('../../assets/tresemme.png');
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-size:cover;
             text-align: center;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response...I added an `ion-item` as a container for the stuff in the `ion-navbar` and gave it the background, and it is working...do you know if u are supposed to use `ion-item` outside an `ion-list`?

Comment: Yes I guess you can use outside in some other tags.  By the way can you pease like and select my answer if you liked it. thx..